# Is there a faster method than UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL I'm using `UNION ALL` to get some data from to different tables, but it's taking a long time to get the results. Is there a faster way to achieve this without using `UNION`?

For example the query looks like this:

```
select * 
from table_1 
where date between '20141001' and '20141020' 
UNION ALL  
select * 
from table_2 
where date between '20141001' and '20141020';
```

Comment: No way to tell unless we see your SQL

Comment: .. and dbms could also be good to know

Comment: The problem is likely not in the UNION but rather in the different queries that you union.

Comment: What is your DBMMS ? What index do you have on your tables ?

Comment: MS SQL , no indexes due to limitations of space

Comment: HDD space is much cheaper than users time. Well, if you are using SQL Express edition, then you may be out of luck - but creating indexes is almost mandatory to get any performance. Otherwise 'union all' is probably fastest way to get data from two tables (and please, use column lists instead of *).

Comment: I agree, indexes are the way to go. You cannot reasonnably expect good performance if you have to make a full scan of both table for a query that simple. Your problems have nothing to do with the UNION. Go fight with your DBAs to get a larger space limit.

Comment: We could provide you more hints if you'd provide some answers:
Which database server are you using? How many rows are returned by this query? Could you provide an execution plan?

Comment: DB server : MS SQL , approximately 2 Millions records

Answer (score 0):

Just few remarks about:

- Consider adding indexes on `date` column on both tables
- Specify the list of columns instead of using `*`
- Double check the datatype of `date` column: it is date or datetime? In case it is datetime, do you really need to be datetime?

Comment: i use * because all the columns needed